# How to set node ip as nameserver in dnsConfig?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-pod, openshift-origin, okd

Im overriding the the dns policy of a pod since I'm facing a [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719383/pod-unable-to-install-packagesapt-get-update-or-apt-get-install) with default `/etc/resolv.conf` of the pod. Another issue is that the pod is not able to connect to smtp server server due to default `/etc/resolv.conf` of the pod

Hence the dnspolicy that is desired to be applied to the deployment/pod is:

```
      dnsConfig:
        nameservers:
          - <ip-of-the-node>
        options:
          - name: ndots
            value: '5'
        searches:
          - monitoring.svc.cluster.local
          - svc.cluster.local
          - cluster.local
      dnsPolicy: None
```

In the above configuration the `nameservers` needs to be IP of the node where pod gets deployed. Since I have three worker nodes, I cannot hard-code the value to specific worker node's IP. I would not prefer configuring the pod to get deployed to particular node since if the resources are not sufficient for the pod to get deployed in a particular node, the pod might remain in pending state.

How can I make the `nameservers` to get value of the IP address of the node where pod gets deployed?

Or is it possible to update the `nameservers` with some kind a of a generic argument so that the pod will be able to connect to smtp server.

Answer (score 4):

`dnsConfig` [support up to 3 IP addresses](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-dns-config) specified so theoretically you could hard code it in the `nameservers` field. However as a workaround you can pass node ip address as a [env variable and then pass it to the pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#envvarsource-v1-core). Example:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: envar-demo-container
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "printenv NODE_IP >> /etc/resolv.conf"]
    image: nginx
    env:
    - name: NODE_IP
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef: 
          fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

`fieldPath: status.hostIP` takes IP address of the node that pod is deployed on and saves it as a environment variable. Then it is written to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the solution, Once i update with above changes im getting a error: `/bin/sh: can't create /etc/resolv.conf: Permission denied` . Im using image `grafana:7.1.5` which is having securityContext `fsGroup` and `runAsUser` as `472`.

Comment: To run the pod as root, I have tried updating securityContext `runAsUser: 0` but unfortunately grafana pod goes into crashloopbackoff with this change

Comment: You can create a pod security policy and run `privileged` pod https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#privileged